# How to replicate CSS layout example

Tags: css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  padding: 2.5rem 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: #c8bfbf;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.navbar-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
}

.list-item {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.footer-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
}

.footer-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-container {
  width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>CSS Assignment</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="navbar-list">
            <li class="list-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="list-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="list-item"><a href="#">Service</a></li>
            <li class="list-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class='header'>
        <h2>We Provide the best IT Services</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, assumenda distinctio. Fugit, quam veritatis
            officia mollitia ex fugiat beatae temporibus.</p>
        <a href="#">Know more...</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet ex itaque voluptates facilis earum quis
            similique, quasi quisquam nesciunt nulla ab esse veritatis molestias. Sapiente dolore molestiae error, quos
            pariatur minima omnis, ipsa quis et a porro dignissimos totam officiis ad quo eos quae natus dicta ullam
            cupiditate tempore? Omnis labore exercitationem eaque asperiores illum praesentium nobis, a velit molestias?
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet ex itaque voluptates facilis earum quis
            similique, quasi quisquam nesciunt nulla ab esse veritatis molestias. Sapiente dolore molestiae error, quos
            pariatur minima omnis, ipsa quis et a porro dignissimos totam officiis ad quo eos quae natus dicta ullam
            cupiditate tempore? Omnis labore exercitationem eaque asperiores illum praesentium nobis, a velit molestias?
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet ex itaque voluptates facilis earum quis
            similique, quasi quisquam nesciunt nulla ab esse veritatis molestias. Sapiente dolore molestiae error, quos
            pariatur minima omnis, ipsa quis et a porro dignissimos totam officiis ad quo eos quae natus dicta ullam
            cupiditate tempore? Omnis labore exercitationem eaque asperiores illum praesentium nobis, a velit molestias?
        </p>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer-content">
        <div class="footer-list">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-list">
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Viemo</a></li>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Can someone help me with this layout?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPZZN.jpg

I am using CSS flexbox to style it but I have a question. How is the header text and the content's width lined up / same width. But also their background extends the full page. Is the content lined up with the same padding? At first I tried using the same margin but my example ended up looking like this.

Mine : https://i.stack.imgur.com/g252K.jpg

Comment: Dear Brian Bui, What you have tried, please put your code also in the question so that you will be helped :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Sorry about that, here is my code. At first I made the body: 1200px; but the background color does not extend the full length of the page like the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made certain changes and did CSS and here is the layout you were looking for.
-user container to wrap

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: auto;
}

nav {
  background: #000;
}

.navbar-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-list>.list-item {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.navbar-list>.list-item a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.header {
  background: #aaaaaa;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.header h2 {
  padding: 0 0 15px;
}

.content p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% / 3 - 30px);
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.content {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.content p:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.content p:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

footer.footer-content {
  background: green;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.footer-lists {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.footer-list>li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.footer-list>li:last-child a {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>CSS Assignment</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="navbar-list">
        <li class="list-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class='header'>
    <div class="container">

      <h2>We Provide the best IT Services</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, assumenda distinctio. Fugit, quam veritatis officia mollitia ex fugiat beatae temporibus.</p>
      <a href="#">Know more...</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet ex itaque voluptates facilis earum quis similique, quasi quisquam nesciunt nulla ab esse veritatis molestias. Sapiente dolore molestiae error, quos pariatur minima omnis, ipsa quis et
        a porro dignissimos totam officiis ad quo eos quae natus dicta ullam cupiditate tempore? Omnis labore exercitationem eaque asperiores illum praesentium nobis, a velit molestias?
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet ex itaque voluptates facilis earum quis similique, quasi quisquam nesciunt nulla ab esse veritatis molestias. Sapiente dolore molestiae error, quos pariatur minima omnis, ipsa quis et
        a porro dignissimos totam officiis ad quo eos quae natus dicta ullam cupiditate tempore? Omnis labore exercitationem eaque asperiores illum praesentium nobis, a velit molestias?
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet ex itaque voluptates facilis earum quis similique, quasi quisquam nesciunt nulla ab esse veritatis molestias. Sapiente dolore molestiae error, quos pariatur minima omnis, ipsa quis et
        a porro dignissimos totam officiis ad quo eos quae natus dicta ullam cupiditate tempore? Omnis labore exercitationem eaque asperiores illum praesentium nobis, a velit molestias?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer-content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="footer-lists">
        <div class="footer-list">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-list">
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Viemo</a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```